# How can I change the color of a toolbar in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I've been trying to change the color of one toolbar for 2 days and I can't find the correct way... Is really frustrating...

Can anybody tells me how I can change this color??

[image: Color I want to change]

Is it possible??

What I've tried:

- Generate an object and overriding the methods:

· `OnEraseBkgnd()`

· `OnCtlColor()`

· `PreparePaint()`

- Getting one method where to insert the color directly
- Search for the rectangle of the control and change de color there
- Using `SetBckgndColor()` method from the `GetToolBarCtld()` object.

thanks

Comment: Can you give a bit more info? How have you defined your toolbar class? What version of MFC/VS are you using? `OnCtlColor()` could work: show us the code for your override, and let's see if we can 'fix' it.

Comment: It's not easy, because MFCprovides its own customizations. First, check the toolbar's runtime class type (yes, use that `IsKindOf()` function), find its code and check what can be changed or set and what's hard-coded. You may even need to subclass it and change your code to create this kind of object instead of the original. Also check the Win32 toolbar control it creates, and what can be changed there.

Comment: If you're using `CToolBar` as a base, then `OnCrlColor()` doesn't get called - at least, when I just tested it, it wasn't called. One *possible* solution is to derive from `CDialogBar` instead - I could change the background color on that with `OnCtlColor()`. But there's a bit of work to do if using this approach.

Comment: @Adrian, I don't think he actually has a choice here. MFC is notorious for not easily allowing such changes, after the application options are initially set. It's not just the class declaration, there are additional operations performed by the framework, like customization, registry reads/updates etc. So, if it is a  `CToolBar`, the only realistic option is a `CToolBar`-derived class (and check what's possible in there). Another possibility is re-create the application, but is this possible at this point, and furthermore will a `CDialogBar`-derived one definitely work?

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou - I agree! Moving to a new base class will present new problems and workload. I mentioned it because, in one of my projects I have 'toolbars' derived from both. I could easily change the B/G colour in the `CDialogBar`-derived class but not in the `CToolBar`-derived one.

Comment: But, on another level, both `CToolBar` and `CDialogBar` are derived (directly) from `CControlBar`, so framework- and registry-related issues may be minimal.